# emmet snippet extension indent head and body from html and insert extra line breaks

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets, emmet, abbreviation

I have a question about indenting and inserting extra blank lines into a starter html5 document using a custom abbreviation in my `snippets.json` extension.

My custom abbreviation looks like this:

`"doc": "html[lang=${locale}]>(head>meta[charset=UTF-8]+title{${1:PageTitle}}+link:css)+(body>(header+main+footer)"`

The above abbreviation produces the following starter html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to indent everything between the `<html>` tags one more level, and insert a blank line after the `<html lang="en-US">`, `</head>`, `</header>`, `</main>`, `</footer>`, and `</html>` tags.

Can anyone offer the solution?

Answer (score 7):

1. Inner indentation of some elements is controlled by `format.noIndentTags` preference: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/ You can simply set this preference to `null` in your `preferences.json`
2. Use `{${newline}}` expression to insert newline. E.g. output `newline` variable in text node. You can also create your own snippet as a shortcut for this expression or create your own snippet that simply outputs newline.

Comment: You should be getting way more upvotes (and even flattrs/gittips/donations) for actively supporting emmet users everywhere, thank you Sergey